# Некорректно отрабатывает транзакция TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql

Есть 2 связанных таблицы. Добавляя запись в одну, во вторую добавляется несколько связанных. Делаю всё это с обвязкой в TransactionScope. В итоге в какой-то момент перестают добавляться записи сначала во вторую таблицу, а потом и в первую.

```cs
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
string query = $"INSERT INTO stat (!!!) VALUES(!!!) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE !!!;";
                    using (var data = AdapterMySql.MathConnection.GetDataTable(query))
                    {
                        foreach (var o in Logs)
                        {
                            string queryLogs = $"INSERT INTO stat2 (!!!) VALUES((SELECT Id FROM stat WHERE id_game='{game.GameId}'), !!!);";
                            AdapterMySql.MathConnection.GetDataTable(queryLogs);
                        }
                    }
scope.Complete();
}
```